# SciPy: Interpolation/Smoothing without edge bleeding

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, raster

I have a raster that is being stored in a numpy array that holds an aerial photo of an area that may be any shape. There is a good amount of noise in the data within the area that needs to be smoothed out. The edge of the image (where no data is) is marked by 0s that extend to the edge of the raster.

I have tried using the gaussian filter in scipy.ndimage.filters, but that reduces the values of the pixels at the edge of the data set. I can't find a flag to set nodata value. Is there a better way to do this in Python?